# How can I determine the set S is subspace or not ? I have to prove it by variables

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following sets:

"To prove that a given subset S is a subspace, you need the conditions to hold universally, so in that case you should indeed use variables and check that linear combinations (equivalently, addition and scalar multiplication) of elements of S still satisfy the defining property of S." This is all I know but i'm struggling with this examples[image]

Comment: Did your teacher give any examples in class? Are there any examples in your textbook? If so, look at those carefully and try to do something similar. By the way, only 5 is a subspace.

Comment: Why don't you sketch the spaces above and guess whether or not they are linear subspaces???

Comment: I have to proove it with variables. I know how to prove with numbers for example 2. (0,2)+(-2,-1)=(-2,1) where -2 is not >=0 so is not vector space but how can I prove it with variables.

Comment: I need the conditions to hold universally.

Comment: And I think that 5 is not subspace, can you prove it why is it? @BernardMassé

Comment: I think **5**. is not a subspace, because it doesn't contain $(0,0)$.  Also, one numerical counterexample suffices to prove something is not a subspace

Comment: Sketch 4, above and tell me why it is not a subspace. What subspaces are bounded?